# Promises.all() is not waiting for the resolution of the promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js code in which I want to wait for all my sql queries to complete 
and then process the next part.

Here I am returning the promises and storing in the array. 
After all the promises are returned I want to do some calculation. 
But it seems that Promises.all() is not waiting for the promises to get resolve and gives me 0 in the calculation stage ?

Can someone help me with this, where I am doing the mistake ?

```
var results= [];
    var salaries = 0;
    var numberOfWorking = 0;
    var numberOfNotFound = 0;
    var numberOfFound = 0;
    var averageSalary = 0;
    var promises = [];
    for (grad in graduates) {
      promises.push(function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          var entree = graduates[grad];
          console.log("entree:", JSON.stringify(entree));
          var query = "SELECT Salary FROM employment WHERE FirstName='" + entree['firstName'] + "' AND MiddleName='" + entree['middleName'] + "'" +
            "AND LastName='" + entree['lastName'] + "' AND DOB='" + entree['birth'] + "'";

          connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (!err) {

              if (rows.length == 0) {
                numberOfNotFound = numberOfNotFound + 1;
              }
              else {

                var Salary = parseInt(rows[0].Salary, 10)
                console.log("Salary", Salary);
                numberOfFound = numberOfFound + 1;
                salaries += Salary;
                if (Salary > 0) {
                  numberOfWorking = numberOfWorking + 1;
                }
                console.log("salaries", salaries);
                console.log("numberOfFound", numberOfFound);
                console.log("numberOfWorking", numberOfWorking);
                resolve(true);
              }
            }
            else {
              console.log(req.body);
              console.log("ERROR:", err);
              reject(err);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function (dataArr) {
      if (numberOfFound > 0) {
        averageSalary = salaries / numberOfFound;
      }
      else {
        averageSalary = 0;
      }
      console.log("salaries", salaries);
      console.log("averageSalary", averageSalary);
      console.log("numberOfFound", numberOfFound);
      console.log("numberOfWorking", numberOfWorking);
      var tosendOnePkg = {};

      tosendOnePkg = {
        "packageID": pId,
        "numberOfPersons": numberOfFound + numberOfNotFound,
        "numberOfWorkingPersons": numberOfWorking,
        "notFoundPersons": numberOfNotFound,
        "averageSalary": averageSalary
      }
      tosendOnePkg['packageID'] = package;
      results.push(tosendOnePkg);
    });
```

Comment: promises seems to be an array of **function** - functions that are never executed at that - try removing `function () {
        return`  - and the corresponding `}`

Comment: also, `tosendOnePkg['packageID'] = package;` seems to be weird code, since package is not defined anywhere and `tosendOnePkg.packageID` is set to `pId` on the previous statement!

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks! Actually this is just a part of code not the full one!

Comment: Sure, but it's odd anyway - also, it may be a "babel" thing, but babel does not like the var name `package`

Comment: You also should avoid having promises that never resolve or reject. In the event your promise enters the first condition and there are no rows, it is never resolved or rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're adding functions to the promise array, see line 9 of your example:

```
promises.push(function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Instead, you should add the promise itself:

```
promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ...
});
```